# cURL Requests through client or user IP

Tags: php, curl

create a file index.php with this code and request this page client.php which purpose to show the ip address of user who will access the page. Whenever somone request through [index.php](http://www.bomberfeeds.com/demo/) its shows the server ip or when someone access [client.php](http://www.bomberfeeds.com/demo/client.php) directly it will shows user or client ip. is this possible to make request through user ip ?

```
$url = 'http://www.bomberfeeds.com/demo/client.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a custom header for example `X-Forwarded-For` and set the user  IP to that header. You can use that header on the other site and work with them. Some loadbalancers do exactly the same and use a custom header for the user ip.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-Forwarded-For: ' . $externalIpAdress,
));
```

Comment: this work for same domain but what if need on cross domain ?